# MySQL: insert select in order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sql-insert

I want to insert data into a table in a specific order. This is because I need to give each entry a specific ID. What I am using is a select statement:

```
select (@i := @i + 1) as id, ...
order by column
```

The problem I am having is that this does not seem to work. I get the result I want from the select query. However, when I try to insert the data into the table the order by statement is ignored. Is there any way to force the correct order in the insert statement?

What I want is this:

```
+----+------+-------------+
| id | name | breadcrumbs |
+----+------+-------------+
|  1 | test | 01          |
|  5 | -d   | 01,05       |
|  4 | c    | 04          |
|  6 | e    | 06          |
|  2 | -a   | 06,02       |
|  3 | --b  | 06,02,03    |
+----+------+-------------+
```

To become this:

```
+----+------+-------------+
| id | name | breadcrumbs |
+----+------+-------------+
|  1 | test | 01          |
|  2 | -d   | 01,05       |
|  3 | c    | 04          |
|  4 | e    | 06          |
|  5 | -a   | 06,02       |
|  6 | --b  | 06,02,03    |
+----+------+-------------+
```

In a separate temporary table.

Comment: You want generate ids based on  sorting  breadcrumbs on a parent,child,grandchild basis - for example 01 first followed by 01,02 followed by 01,02,03 followed by 01,03 followed by 02 followed by 02,01 and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make certain that @i is initalised see select in from clause below

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t(id int, name varchar(10), breadcrumbs varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t values
    -> (  1 , 'test' , '01'      ),
    -> (  5 , '-d'   , '01,05'   ),
    -> (  4 , 'c'    , '04'      ),
    -> (  6 , 'e'    , '06'      ),
    -> (  2 , '-a'   , '06,02'   ),
    -> (  3 , '--b'  , '06,02,03');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t1 as
    -> select
    -> @i:=@i+1 id,
    ->  t.name,t.breadcrumbs
    -> from  (select @i:=0) i,
    -> t
    -> order by breadcrumbs;
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.22 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t1;
+------+------+-------------+
| id   | name | breadcrumbs |
+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | test | 01          |
|    2 | -d   | 01,05       |
|    3 | c    | 04          |
|    4 | e    | 06          |
|    5 | -a   | 06,02       |
|    6 | --b  | 06,02,03    |
+------+------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to insert data into a table in a specific order.

There is no internal order to the records in a MySQL database table.  Tables are modeled after unordered sets.  The only order which exists is the one you apply by using an `ORDER BY` clause when you query.  So moving forward, instead of worrying about the order in which your records are inserted, you should instead make sure that your table has the necessary columns and data to order your result sets the way you want.